# Permutation Homework

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are two teams.Two games were played.There are three possible outcomes which are win, lose or draw. how many permutations are there?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you edit your question to add your thoughts (however silly you may think they are) it is much more likely to get you help

Comment: This is few enough that you can list them by hand.  This may help you see a pattern for larger problems.

Answer (score 1):

Teams A, B

In any game, if team A wins, team B loses. If team A loses, team B wins...etc. So the outcome for any one team determines the outcome for the other.

So we need only consider the outcomes for team A, given team A  plays two games against B.

$1\quad2$ : Game
$W \;\;W$
$W \;\; L$
$W\;D $
$L\;\;W$
$L\;\;L$
$L\;\;D$
$D\;\;W$
$D\;\;L$
$D\;\;D$

In all, there are $9$ possible outcomes when two teams play two games.

Answer (score 0):

The first outcome can either be a win, lose or draw. Let's assume that it was a win. In this case, the second outcome can also have $3$ possibilities. If the first outcome was instead either a lose or draw, even then in both cases, the second outcome can either be win, lose or draw.

Thus the total permuations is $3+3+3=9$

In general, if there were $n$ games played, then the number of permutations would be $3^n$.